# Using GPU with multithreading in C

Tags: c, multithreading, gpu

I have a brute force program with multithreading implemented using pthreads in C. This has been sent to a server using PUTTY.

My task is to implement a brute force attack using GPUs. My question is, do I need to add anything more or will the compiler automatically utilize the GPU to carry out the multithreading?

Comment: A C compiler will not use a GPU, you need something like [OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) to be able to utilize a GPU.

Comment: Take a look at [CUDA](https://developer.nvidia.com/how-to-cuda-c-cpp), if NVIDIA is applicable for you.

Comment: So do I install OpenCL/CUDA on my machine or on the server?

Comment: On the GPU-machine. Best to compile your code there, as well.

Comment: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide

Comment: If for example your brute force attack is to feed every number from 1 to 100 through a one-way hash until you hit the target hash, you can easily invoke this C function to run on 100 GPU threads simultaneously using the simple 1 dimensional kernel invocation. Avoid "if" statements in computing your hash to get best benefits from SIMD.